# Hyperplane $\Phi_X$ in Chow construction (Algebraic Geometry by Joe Harris)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes, birational-geometry, moduli-space

I'm trying to figure out what Harris wanted to say in following
construction, called Chow construction (Algebraic Geometry by Joe Harris, p. 269):

> The first construction of the parameter space for varieties of a given degree and
> dimension is called the Chow construction. The basic idea behind it is simply that
> the problem in parametrizing varieties $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ in general is that $X$
> is not generally given by a single polynomial, whose coefficients we can vary freely
> as in the example
> of hypersurfaces. The point of the construction is thus to associate to any such
> variety $X$ a hypersurface $\Phi_X$, albeit not one in a projective space.

> There are two essentially equivalent ways of doing this. Suppose first of all that $X$
> has pure dimension $k$, and consider the
> incidence correspondence consisting of points $p \in X$ together with $(k + 1)$-tuples of
> hyperplanes containing $p$; that is,

$$  \Gamma = \{(p, H_1,..., H_{k+1}): \ p \in H_i \forall i \} $$
$$ \subset X \times (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* \times ... \times (\mathbb{P}^{n})^*  $$

> ($(\mathbb{P}^{n})^*$ is the dual projective space) for each point
> $p \in X$, the set of hyperplanes containing $p$ is a hyperplane
> $\mathbb{P}^{n-1} \subset (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* $, so that the
> set of $(k + 1)$-tuples of hyperplanes is irreducible of dimension $(k + 1) \cdot (n - 1)$. We
> deduce that $\Gamma$ is of pure dimension $k + (k + 1) \cdot (n - 1) = (k + 1)· n - 1$, with one
> irreducible component corresponding to each irreducible component of $X$.

> For a general choice of point
> $p \in X$ and $H_1,..., H_{k+1}$ containing $p$ the
> intersection of the $H_i$ with $X$ will consist only of the point $p$, so that the
> canonical projection map $\pi: \Gamma \to (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* \times ... \times (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* $
> will be birational. It follows that the image of $\Gamma$ under
> this projection is a hypersurface in
> $(\mathbb{P}^{n})^* \times ... \times (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* $ (this is where we need X to have
> pure dimension); we will call this hypersurface $\Phi_X$.

*Question:* The last sentences I not understand. If a map between
$f: X \to Y$ varieties/ schemes of pure dimension is *birational* then the image
(and also it's closure in $Y$) cannot be contained in a subvariety $W \subset Y$ of smaller
dimension than $\dim Y (= \dim \ X$ as $f$ birational). But a hypersurface of $Y$ has
properly smaller dimension than $Y$ so the map cannot be birational.

Therefore I not understand why the projection map
$\pi: \Gamma \to (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* \times ... \times (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* $
is birational and a hypersurface of $(\mathbb{P}^{n})^* \times ... \times (\mathbb{P}^{n})^* $
contains the image of $\Gamma$.

Comment: The intended meaning is that the projection is birational on to its image. You can check by the dimension count earlier in the quoted text.